# How do I sum all the numbers in a range using this function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working through this coding challenge on [Free Code Camp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sum-all-numbers-in-a-range)

```
We'll pass you an array of two numbers. 
Return the sum of those two numbers and all numbers between them. 
The lowest number will not always come first.
```

They suggest to use `Math.max(), Math.min(), Array.reduce()`, however I began working through a solution which did not use any of those methods—but soon discovered maybe I should have because my version began to look a little clunky.

```
function sumAll(arr){
    var index0 = arr[0], index1 = arr[1], counter = 0, sum = 0, val;
    if(index0 < index1){
         counter += index0;
        while(counter <= index1){
              val = index0++;  
              sum += val;     
              counter++;
         }

  } else if(index0 > index1){
         counter = 1;
         counter += index0;
        while(counter >= index1){
              val = index1 + 1;  
              sum += val;     
             counter--;
         }
    }
   return sum;
}
```

Basically this works save for when you try:

```
sumAll([10, 5]) //I get 42, rather than 45
```

So my two questions are the following:

Am I correct in the fact it's getting clunky?
And should I have used the aforementioned methods which were recommended? 
I think I just got excited when stuff when I got things to work but now I feel I am going down a rabbit hole with another potential condition..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `min`, `max` and one `loop`

```js
var sumAll = function(arr) {
  var sum = 0,
    min = Math.min.apply(null, arr),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumAll([10, 5]))
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, I like your solution very straightforward! And much less code! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bit faster version that takes advantage of the fact that you don't have to actually add every single sequential number in a sequence, but you can calculate that sum based on the start and end point:

```
function sumAll(args) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, args),
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, args);
  return min + ((max - min) * ((max + min + 1) / 2));
}
```

And, here's a test bed: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rh75gesc/ which compares it to the old fashioned way for accuracy.

---

For pure performance (not code brevity), it's probably better to just compare the two values rather than make two function calls:

```
function sumAllFaster(args) {
    var min, max;
    if (args[0] < args[1]) {
        min = args[0];
        max = args[1];
    } else {
        min = args[1];
        max = args[0];
    }
    return min + ((max - min) * ((max + min + 1) / 2));
}
```

If you test this against the @NenadVracar answer and include some large ranges, this last version is up to 100 times faster.  The longer the range, the more of a speed difference.  Even with short ranges, it is 3-4x faster.  Timed tests here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5daztnky/.

Here's a slightly faster version:

```
function sumAllFastest(args) {
    var diff = args[0] < args[1] ? args[1] - args[0] : args[0] - args[1];
    return (1 + diff) * ((args[0] + args[1]) / 2)
}
```

Comment: Added some notes about performance testing of the various options.

Comment: No, you've just stolen my (pure math) ternary and added it to your collection. 
But no matter what do, mine is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit slower version, but it's in ES6, which is cool

```
function sumAll(arr, n=1){
    const [min, max] = arr.sort();
    return Array(max+n).fill(0,min-n,max+n).reduce((a,b,i) => a+i);
}
```

Comment: Just curious.  Why is creating an array just so you can sum sequential values cool?

Comment: @jfriend00 - because ... it's ES6

Comment: @РоманПарадеев - clever, destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that, when saying: "an array of numbers", he/she didn't mean an Array Object containing those two numbers. So I offer you this Spartan JS:

```
function sum_range(x,y){ return( 1 + ( x < y ? y - x : x - y ) ) * (x + y) / 2; }
```

p.s.: It can be found on my FB timeline.

But even than, you are reassured that the supposed array will contain only two peripheral numbers of the range;

So it's all the same. The change is in the way of passing arguments to the function, e.g.:

```
console.log( sum_range( arr[0], arr[1] ) );
```

v.s.:

```
console.log( sum_range( 10, 5 ) );
```

Comment: The question says in no uncertain terms: `We'll pass you an array of two numbers.` Can't be much more clear than that.

Comment: for every couple of two or more numbers; items; etc the word array  can be used.

Comment: Performance wise, my Spartan is still (~25%) faster than your fastest, even if I have to cripple it to suit your test algo made for a single argument array input as in:

`function sum_range(x){ return( 1 + ( x[0] < x[1] ? x[1] - x[0] : x[0] - x[1] ) ) * (x[0] + x[1]) / 2; }`

@jfriend00 just so that you'd know, you can test it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, your calculation is slightly simpler.  Uhh, "crippled" isn't the word I'd use here - that's the specification the OP asked for.  The main point for the OP of both our answers is that you can directly calculate the result without summing a series of numbers.

Comment: Everything deprived of its optimal performance is crippling. And we were talking "speed".
You see, Math object is not exactly a native JavaScript object. My Spartan  is faster, because it doesn't rely on Math object invocation, doesn't iterate, and doesn't create new variables but simply returns a basic math result.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way to solve this would be to:

1. Find **min** and **max** of the input array.
2. From  **min** to **max** sum all the numbers.

Something like this:

```
sumAll = function(arr) {
var low_bound = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
var up_bound = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);

result = 0;
for (i=low_bound;i<=up_bound;i++){
    result += i;
}
return result
```

}